# Why isn't .text or .html working

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, html

I have a span:

```
<span id="unreadbadge" class="badge red">0</span>
```

and a script that says on the executed function do this:

```
var arrayOfUnRead = jQuery.parseJSON(text);
jQuery("#unreadbadge").text(arrayOfUnRead.length);
confirm(arrayOfUnRead.length);
```

Though "1" the right value of arrayOfUnRead.length is called back from confirm the span with the id unreadbadge still remains with its same content "0". I have tried .html to and receive the same results. I am running this on Wordpress if that helps.

`text` is:

> [{"id":"1","message":"Hello Users","conversation_id":"1","sender":"kdogisthebest","sent_on":"2013-03-12 13:45:58","read_by":"kdogisthebest"}]

Comment: may be yo u have to stringify json

Comment: What is `text`? Does it have a value?

Comment: yes it is json and if I confirmed it I can see its data

Comment: I just tried `document.getElementById("unreadbadge").innerHTML="someContent";` and it didn't change anything

Comment: Actually, I meant, can you post the value of `text`? That way we can try what you're trying.

Comment: I have tested my answer's code with your string of information and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var text = "[2,55,42]";
var arrayOfUnRead = $.parseJSON(text);
var lengthOfUnread = arrayOfUnRead.length;
$("#unreadbadge").text(lengthOfUnread);
confirm(lengthOfUnread);
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCCjB/

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still receiving 0.

Comment: Checkout my updated answer (Although it's basically the same) but checkout the jsFiddle to see it working.

Comment: Yes I see. I put the exact same code in my site http://kitb.tk and it shows confirm but the span at the top right doesn't change

Comment: Okay, it appears that this page has more than one `#unreadbadge`. You can only have one id with a specific name, so that appears to be your problem. The easiest way to fix this would just be to change from using an ID to using a class. Just add the class 'unreadbadge' and change the selector accordingly and it should work.

Comment: Wow, I just realized that wordpress was adding two menus and thus two badges. Thanks for pointing this out to me!